# Cannot access stack elements from another method - Assembly

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, nasm, sasm

I am messing around with assembly(NASM) lately, and I came up with the program bellow, which has two files. The name and the code of each file is:

> mainprogram.asm:

```
%include "hello.asm"

section .data
    message db 'Hello World!', 10, 0

section .text
global _main
_main:
    push message
    call print_message
    ret
```

> hello.asm

```
extern _printf
section .text
global print_message
print_message:
    call _printf
    add esp, 4
    ret
```

Now, if I run this program I get a segmentation error. My question is this: The program has a different stack when we call a method/routine from another file ? Because this is the only conclusion that I can come up with. I tried to find a reasoning through google, but I cannot find anything relevant. If someone can help me with that, it would be great.

Comment: Move `add esp, 4` from `print_message` to `_main` after `call print_message`. If using CDECL calling convention it is the caller who cleans up the stack after a call, not the function called.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Now it prints to the console, but not the intended message; it prints garbage.

Comment: Because in `print_message` you haven't pushed a copy of the message address on the stack to make the call to `_printf`.

Comment: `print_message` will have to look something like `print_message:`
    `push dword [esp+4]`
    `call _printf`
    `add esp, 4`
    `ret`

Comment: Now it works, but I cannot understand why it works like that. In the `mainprogram.asm`, I `push` the message of the stack. So why I have to `push` it again in `print_message` ? And also, why `esp+4` ? Since I `push`ed the message on the stack in `mainprogram.asm`, shouldn't `esp` point at it ?

Comment: Because when you use the CALL instruction it pushes the return address on the stack. If you don't push a copy of the parameter passed to `print_message` the return address on the top of the stack will be used as input to `_printf` and thus why it printed garbage.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Silly me ... I should have known better that assembly didn't a had an automatic way of going back, and thus it had a way of saving the return address somewhere. Sir, you are a savior. This thing made me bang my head and keyboard for three and a half hours. If you want, add it as a solution in order to get the credits. Otherwise I will add it as an edit to the topic. In any case, I thank you very very much!

Comment: I guess this has probably "duplicate" asking about how `call/ret` works, with some nice answer (although I can't recall seeing one, I just remember similar questions do pop here from time to time, but usually they are pushed back by mere comment or url link to Instruction reference guide) (pop/push pun intended)... maybe somebody skilled in searching duplicates will help.